# OOP JavaScript - public variable undefined

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm having a problem with the scope of a public variable in javascript. The variable is declared in the main function (function Level) of my javascript class. The loadXML function is called from outside the class, but knows the this.layers variable. When my xml is loaded and redirected to another function the this.layers variable suddenly is undefined. Anyone having experience with this kind of problem.

```
var Level = (function()
{

function Level()
{
    this.layers = 3;
}

Level.prototype.loadXML = function()
{
    console.log(this.layers); //variable is defined!
    $.get("xml/level_" + this.currentLevel + ".xml", Level.buildGrid);
};

Level.buildGrid = function(xml)
{
    console.log(this.layers); //variable is undefined!
};

return Level;

})();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you mean to use `Level.prototype.buildGrid = function()` rather than `Level.buildGrid`...

Comment: I wanted the Level.buildGrid to be a private function, so I dropped the prototype which seems to work.

Comment: no this way what you did was making it a static function. If you want it private, declare it inside the constructor as a simple function, it will not be visible outside

Comment: you can also choose to name your function with a leading _, like _buildGrid, it is common for function that are public but should be treated as private

Answer (score 1):

Return a new function from `buildGrid` that will be passed as jQuery's callback and pass to the wrapped function the current level so that you can get informations from the argument passed. The `buildGrid` function is so private to the `Level`'s closure and can be accessed only inside it.

```
var Level = (function () {
    var buildGrid = function (level) {
        return function(xml) {
            console.log(xml);
            console.log(level.layers);
        };
    };
    function Level() {
        this.layers = 3;
    }
    Level.prototype.loadXML = function () {
        console.log(this.layers); //variable is defined!
        $.get("xml/level_" + this.currentLevel + ".xml", buildGrid(this));
    };
    return Level;
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

this.layers only exists within the scope of level which is a *constructur*.

try the following:

```
var t = new Level.Level()
t.layers
```